# iPod restored in iTunes: but now in Xcode: No provisioned iOS device is connected

Tags: xcode, ios

I restored my iPod in iTunes, but now in Xcode I get the following:

> Error Starting Executable
>
> No provisioned iOS device is connected. Please check the Organizer to view the status of any connected devices.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you done what the error told you to do? What does the Organizer say about your iPod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did a factory restore on your iPod Touch, you wiped out the provisioning profile that allows you to install developer apps on the device. Do what the error message says: Go to XCode's Organizer window (Command-Shift-2) and reinstall your provisioning profile.